# Email using localhost's port 25?

Tags: sockets, smtp, posix

My site is hosted on a shared Linux server and I wrote a C function using sockets to send myself emails. The emails are sent without problems as long as I send them to myself. Emails to myself are sent without username and password. But if I send them to gmail, etc. they get rejected because they complain about *localhost*.

- Is it possible to send to gmail etc. using *localhost* ?
- If I need my username and password at what point in the process is it done? (It is not specified in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)'s examples nor in this [Perl](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node180.html) example.)

This is what I currently do:

1. Use socket() to open port 25 on localhost.
2. write / read from socket for the following:

```
HELO localhost
MAIL FROM: myemail@mydomain.com
RCPT TO: myemail@mydomain.com
DATA
blahblah
QUIT
```

Comment: You could invoke sendmail (or equivalent) via an exec() call.

Answer (score 1):

You really should be sending your host name, rather than `localhost`.
Many servers will reject messages with nonsensical hosts, messages from servers that are not associated with the envelope domain, and from servers that exist in one of the many DNSRBLs.

Local policy may also be prohibiting mail relaying, you might need to ask your hosting provider for an appropriate mail relay.

Inter server message delivery does not generally require authentication.

You may want to consider using a library such as [libsmtp](http://libsmtp.berlios.de/) to handle the protocol details.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the destination server performs a [reverse DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) to determine whether the domain name is associated with the IP of your SMTP server.

For example, if you send an email as `admin@example.com`, the destination server will perform a reverse DNS lookup to determine if the IP of your server is associated with (resolves to) `example.com`.

I suggest reading about [Forward-confirmed reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_Confirmed_reverse_DNS).

Comment: That would be very unusual, since it would not allow one mail server to serve more than one domain, and anyway the IP owner in theory has control of the reverse DNS. What's actually sometimes done is to do a forward lookup (from `example.com`) for a SPF record. That's for the `MAIL FROM` address, though, which isn't the question here. For the `HELO` server identifier, a forward lookup (simply comparing the A record against the IP) would make the most sense.

Comment: @Random832: no, it would allow. The PTR response may contain multiple records. FCrDNS relies on reverse lookups.

Comment: Still has the problem of requiring the "main" domain (example.com rather than mail.example.com) to carry a bunch of records for what may be dedicated mail servers... if we're talking about A records, then you've got the problem of if someone wants to go to http://example.com - SPF works because it doesn't contaminate other uses of DNS.

Comment: Not all DNS servers support SPF - it's experimental. I wouldn't rely on this. Still, SPF uses FCrDNS, which uses reverse lookups.